# how to recognize user's device in android app

Tags: android

I am building an app that collects information on the user's use in the app.
I want to recognize the device that used the app according to  device id or something like that...
what's the easiest way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can get device id, sim serial number, and android id.

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String device_id = tm.getDeviceId();
String serial_number = tm.getSimSerialNumber();
String android_id = android.provider.Settings.Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Settings.Secure#ANDROID_ID
It returns 64 hex String

```
import android.provider.Settings.Secure;

private String android_id = Secure.getString(getContext().getContentResolver(),
                                                    Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```